# How to enable serverside render support for servicestack angular 2 template?

Tags: angular, servicestack, server-side-rendering

with latest release of servicestack there is angular 2 template. How to enable serverside render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't support server side rendering, that would require using node.js to execute the JS on the server through something like JavaScriptServices which is only supported in .NET Core.